# Searching data older than a Date with typeORM

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I am executing a query to **Postgre DB** to fetch data older than a specific date.

Here's my function

```
async filesListToDelete(): Promise<any> {
  return await this.fileRepository.find({
    where: { last_modified: { $lt: '2018-11-15 10:41:30.746877' } },
  });
}
```

Here's how I defined my File entity:

```
export class File {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  idFonc: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  version: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 100, nullable: false })
  filename: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  last_modified: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  device: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(type => Type, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  type: Type;

  @OneToMany(type => FileDevice, filedevice => filedevice.file)
  fileDevice: FileDevice[];
}
```

I get this error

```
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "{"$lt":"2018-11-15 10:41:30.746877"}"
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use LessThan, the [doc](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options)

```
async filesListToDelete(): Promise<any> {
  return await this.fileRepository.find({
   where: { 
       last_modified:  LessThan('2018-11-15  10:41:30.746877') },
});}
```

Comment: Apologies, aren't they looking for LessThan b/c they're looking for data OLDER than that date? (And MoreThan will return more recent data?)

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you need to get an older date, you should be looking for a date less than the current date. You should use LessThan

Answer (score 29):

Also you can do this using `createQueryBuilder` as below:

```
    public async filesListToDelete(): Promise<any> {
        let record = await this.fileRepository.createQueryBuilder('file')
            .where('file.last_modified > :start_at', { start_at: '2018-11-15  10:41:30.746877' })
            .getMany();

        return record
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

Either of these will fetch `OLDER` data

with built-in `TypeORM` operator ([docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options))

```
async filesListToDelete(): Promise<any> {
  return await this.fileRepository.find({
    where: { last_modified:  LessThan('2018-11-15  10:41:30.746877') },
  });
}
```

with `PostgreSQL` operator ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparison.html))

```
public async filesListToDelete(): Promise<any> {
    let record = await this.fileRepository.createQueryBuilder('file')
        .where('file.last_modified < :start_at', { start_at: '2018-11-15  10:41:30.746877' })
        .getMany();

    return record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fetched the data using typeORM and PostgreSQL:

Query:
`"payment.userId = :userId AND payment.pgTxnNo = :transactionNumber AND payment.createdDateTime >= :timestampFrom AND payment.createdDateTime <= :timestampTo"`

Params:

```
{
  userId: "c2ba135e",
  transactionNumber: "1234",
  timestampFrom: "2023-11-15T10:30:35",
  timestampTo: "2023-11-15T10:30:35",
}
```

**Here are the full codes:**

```
async fetchDetails(userId, transactionNumber, timestampFrom, timestampTo): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const query = "payment.userId = :userId AND payment.pgTxnNo = :transactionNumber AND payment.createdDateTime >= :timestampFrom AND payment.createdDateTime <= :timestampTo";

      const  params  = {
               userId: "c2ba135e-7dfc-4f2b-91bf-124d76754965",
               transactionNumber: "1234",
               timestampFrom: "2023-11-15T10:30:35",
               timestampTo: "2023-11-15T10:30:35",
        }

      const [users, totalCount] = await this.paymentRepo
        .createQueryBuilder('payment')
        .select([
          'payment.createdBy',
          'payment.pgTxnAmt',
        ])
        .where(query)
        .setParameters(params)
        .getManyAndCount();
      return { users, totalCount };
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
    }
  }
```